# Remove left margin from Android Toolbar

Tags: java, android, xml, toolbar, android-togglebutton

I am developing an android app in which there is navigation drawer to navigate to other parts of my app. I have changed the ActionBarDrawerToggle default hamburger icon to my own icon. I want to place the toggle icon to the left most part of it. So I want to remove the default 16dp space.

[image: I want to remove that red bordered space to the left of the toggle icon]

I want to remove that red bordered space to the left of the toggle icon

I have already searched for more than 4 hours in the internet but nothing is working. I have tried everything that I found in StackOverflow but none is working. I also tried changing my icon resource to other images to be sure that my used image does not have any error.

Also if I remove the toggle icon from the Toolbar then other content of the Toolbar automatically comes to the extreme left without the 16dp margin but if I add the toggle icon then again the 16dp space is shown.

Also since my minimum sdk version is 18 so some solution which I saw needs minimum sdk version 21 will not work.

The only thing that is working for me is

```
    toolbar.setPadding(-16, 0, 0, 0);
    toolbar.setX(-16);
```

But there is a problem in this, for larger screen device like tablets the toggle icon completely gets hidden. So could anyone please help me with this, below is my code that I am using.

Thanks a lot in advance

```
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    final DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
        }
    };

    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (drawer.isDrawerVisible(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        }
    });
    toolbar.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);
    toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
    toggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.mipmap.toggle);// my icon resource
    toggle.syncState();
```

My xml file for toolbar is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:subtitleTextColor="@color/black"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/black" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your code:

```java
    toolbar.setPadding(-16, 0, 0, 0);
    toolbar.setX(-16);
```

it is different for different screens because your are using pixels (px) and it can change in different screens densities try something like:

```java
toolbar.setPadding(-toPixels(betterValue), 0, 0, 0);
toolbar.setX(-toPixels(betterValue));
/*
.
.
.
*/
static int toPixels(float dip, Context context){
        Resources r=context.getResources();
        float densidade = r.getDisplayMetrics().density;
        return (int)(dip*densidade+0.5f);
}
```

I don't know if this is the better way but i hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. +1 for you. It is working perfectly upto few variation of screens but still I saw in few larger devices it is showing little problem